# result contains no cookies when using result.withCookies

Tags: session, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

*please note: Play Framework newbie*

**Intro**

I need to use `session()` and/or `response().cookies` to pass data/store data.

At first `session()` started with this issue, now `cookies` are following along.

**Problem:**

Given a basic example code below, I have a boolean value setting a result, followed by cookies being created and added to the result.

Here on, the myPage is rendered, which contains a POST action to an action within the same controller, `UserController`

In this new method, there are no `cookies`. This is confirmed by

```
Collection<Http.Cookie> cookies = response().cookies();
```

with a size of `0`

UserController

```
//...
Result result;
if(b)
    result = ok(myPage.render());
else
    result = new MyController().index();
result = result.withCookies(
        new Http.Cookie("id", "value", 86400, "", "", true, false, Http.Cookie.SameSite.LAX),
        new Http.Cookie("id_2", "value_2", 3600, "", "", true, false, Http.Cookie.SameSite.LAX)
    );

return result;
//...
```

**Question:**

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaSessionFlash#Session-Timeout-/-Expiration) states that a `session()` lasts the entire duration while the browser window is open.

Cookies are stored client side and loaded when the webpage loads, session is regarded a bunch of cookies.

Why would setting `session()` entries or adding `cookies()` as shown above, be cleared, i.e. no cookies available in the `response()`?

What can I look for, what would remove `session()` or `cookie` entries?

Comment: I would start by seeing if the clients gets the cookies or not. Use a web inspector or curl to see if the response sent by the server contains the expected cookies, then go from there.

Comment: @FredericA. Hi, thanks for the response. I am unsure of Google Chrome's object inspector qualifies as a `web inspector`, but when using this object inspector, I do not find any session or cookie strings, leading me to believe I am doing something wrong or utilising `session()` and `cookies` incorrectly, in some way.

Comment: Looking at play's source, I'm not sure the way you create the cookie is correct, especially the path and domain. Try building cookies using `Http.Cookie.builder("name", "value).withXXX....build()` do not call call `.withPath` or `.withDomain` with an empty string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there was no secret answer...

This is not shown in the question, but cookies `name` or `id` may contain no spaces. This was causing my problems. After removing the spaces in the `name`/`id` (values could have spaces),

then the issue was resolved